# Django Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '\x80\xc7\xda\x9e'

Tags: python, django, digital-ocean

I am getting errors from Django 1.7 application hosted in Digital ocean.

Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '\x80\xc7\xda\x9e'. The domain name provided is not valid according to RFC 1034/1035.

```
Request repr():
<WSGIRequest
path:/xmlrpc.php,
GET:<QueryDict: {}>,
POST:<QueryDict: {}>,
COOKIES:{},
META:{'HTTP_CONNECTION': 'close',
 'HTTP_HOST': '\x80\xc7\xda\x9e',
 'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT x.y; Win64; x64; rv:10.0)Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0',
 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR': '181.214.92.100',
 'PATH_INFO': u'/xmlrpc.php',
 'QUERY_STRING': '',
 'RAW_URI': '/xmlrpc.php',
 'REMOTE_ADDR': '181.214.92.100',
 'REMOTE_PORT': '80',
 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'POST',
 'SCRIPT_NAME': u'',
 'SERVER_NAME': '\x80\xc7\xda\x9e',
 'SERVER_PORT': '80',
 'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.0',
 'SERVER_SOFTWARE': 'gunicorn/18.0',
 'gunicorn.socket': <socket._socketobject object at 0x7fb05e3e1280>,
 'wsgi.errors': <open file '<stderr>', mode 'w' at 0x7fb0663e01e0>,
 'wsgi.file_wrapper': <class gunicorn.http.wsgi.FileWrapper at   0x7fb063c1b7a0>,
 'wsgi.input': <gunicorn.http.body.Body object at 0x7fb05e3bf810>,
 'wsgi.multiprocess': False,
 'wsgi.multithread': False,
 'wsgi.run_once': False,
 'wsgi.url_scheme': 'http',
 'wsgi.version': (1, 0)}>
```

I have set ALLOWED_HOSTS=['*'] in my base file. What is the cause of this error and how can i resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like someone is testing your webservice for invalid requests (disallowed characters in the host field).

This should be rejected at the webserver level already and not being passed down to gunicorn and Django.

It seems to be an automated attack on PHP sites so it will most likely not harm you. But you should reconfigure the webserver to reject this kind of bad headers.

Comment: Can you suggest any tutorials or link to handle these kinds of errors (preferring nginx)

Comment: Questions about webserver configuration are better placed an Server Fault than Stack Overflow. You will get better help there.